# How to login as root user to Oracle's rman

Tags: oracle, rman

I am trying to login rman as the root user:

```
rman target /

Recovery Manager: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jan 8 21:40:47 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-04005: error from target database: 
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

But I get this error.

I can login using the following

```
rman target sys/oracle@orcl
```

But I want to login as a root user. How can I do this?

Comment: The important question is not how you can do this, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: I would like to backup a database using rman. that is why

Comment: and why root? why not the oracle install owner? That was the question, not why you want to use rman.

Comment: Yes root or oracle install owner. I would like to know how I could login as one.

Comment: did you setup your env correctly, I mean the ORACLE_HOME/SID/...? Can you add them to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Step 01: Findout which OS group currently having SYSDBA privilege (This depends on your installation Oracle Software, but usually it is dba OS group).

Step 02: Modify supplementary Group of root to that group (dba in this example).
Optional: modify PATH having $ORACLE_HOME/bin, setting appropriate ORACLE_SID & ORACLE_HOME.

:) good luck